# Find the Girlfriend

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

Over the past few weeks, I've had a strong feeling that my husband has been secretly dating someone, but I don't know who she is. I asked one of his close friends about it but instead of telling her name he gave me a piece of paper. I think it's a puzzle and I need to solve it to find that girl.

The text written on the paper is:

> a1b1a7b3a6b2

Please help me solve it and find the name...

**HINT 1:**

> Requires Binary conversions

**HINT 2:**

> Requires Binary conversion in 2nd or 3rd step, not in very 1st.

**HINT 3:**

> thecoder16 didn't post the answer but you can proceed with his idea, the very first step:) i.e. convert letter to number and repeat:P

**HINT 4:**

> I got to know that she is also a **Puzzling User!**

Comment: Maybe she is "her"?

Comment: Using a=0, b=1, and taking all numbers mod 2, we get that your husband is clearly dating someone named W :P

Comment: @thecoder16 not saying if you are right or wrong but you can consider posting a answer if like, even partial answers are welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### I think I got it now

We have `a1b1a7b3a6b2`.

The first step is

> the letter should be repeated by its following number resulting `abaaaaaaabbbaaaaaabb`.

The next one is

> converting 'a' to 0 and 'b' to 1, we got a binary string `01000000011100000011`.

Formatting it nice we got

> `0100 0000 0111 0000 0011` which if we convert them to decimal number we will get `40703`.

Finally,

> that means https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40703 which is indeed the author itself, **Preet**.

Comment: your very first step is correct, second could be right if you change a bit:)

Comment: the second step may be to convert 'a' to 0 and 'b' to 1, resulting  `01000000011100000011` but still no idea what next

Comment: yes, now you got the correct binary string, now you are two step away from name so you will not get a name directly from it:) consider all hints

Comment: Well Done!! correct:)

Answer (score 1):

> as per ASCII Code a=97, b=98 so we subtract the next number we get mobile number as Jordan country code 96-9790959196

Comment: Nice try!! but not the correct way. Plz consider hint

Answer (score 1):

I doubt I'm right, but with

> a=Consonant and b=Vowel
>  and the number following it being the rank among the Consonants/Vowels in the alphabet

That would give

> Bajihe

Comment: so why they are given hint.

Comment: @Wizou, sorry its not the answer, binary conversion is necessary

Answer (score 1):

We have the data: **a1 b1 a7 b3 a6 b2**

And I came out with this conversion:
a - 0001
b - 0001
a - 0111
b - 0011
a - 0110
b - 0010

Combining all the pairs of binary numbers, I got this:
**00010001 01110011 01100010**

I couldn't think further from this, as converting this to Hex and finding a letter for name created dangerous names, so I just thought this (illogical) way of solving:
The first number has 2 1's, so the total is 2. = "**B**"
The second number has 5 1's, so the total is 5 = "**E**"
The third number has 3 1's, so the total is 3 = "**C**"

So according to me, the name should be **BEC** or **BECK**.

Comment: Good try I must say, but you gone wrong on very first step otherwise you could find solution. HINT: Binary conversion needed in 2nd or 3rd step(depends if you consider it 2nd or 3rd) not in first.